# Is there any way to figure out query row result belong to which condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have stored my all possible where conditions in an array. This array will contains about 100 records. Each individual array consists of around 11 fields whose relation in query can by `=`, `>` or `<`

```
$wheres =  [
  0 => array:11 [
    "manufacturertuev" => "ALFA ROMEO"
    "power" => 178
    ...

  ]
  1 => array:11 [
    "manufacturertuev" => "ALFA ROMEO"
    "power" => 179
    "ccm" => 1929
    ....
  ]
  ....
]
```

So based on above conditions I will write query something like this:

```
SELECT
     c.tag, 
     DATE(c.supplementDate) as supplementDate
FROM
    cars.cars as c
WHERE
    (
        c.manufacturerTuev = "ALFA ROMEO"
        AND c.power = 178
        ...
    )
    OR
    (
    c.manufacturerTuev = "ALFA ROMEO"
        AND c.power = 179
    )
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

My problem is above query returns me 1000 results but is it possible to know which row belongs to which condition.

For example first 10 rows belong to `c.manufacturerTuev = "ALFA ROMEO" AND c.power = 178`

and second (may be 15) belongs to `c.manufacturerTuev = "ALFA ROMEO" AND c.power = 179`

Can anybody please help me?

Thank You.

Comment: perhaps you could use union and add a constant in the selectlist

Comment: @aschoerk if I have 1000 $wheres then I need to make 1000 times UNION. Will this make the system slow ?

Comment: *is it possible to know which row belongs to which condition.* In shown query form - no. Your filters must be row source (table), not conditions set. I.e. you need in (schematically) `SELECT conditions.id, car.* FROM cars JOIN ({conditions as subquery}) AS conditions ON {apply conditions}`. Possible realization depends on precise MySQL version.

Comment: Let the optimizer decide for you. Or-Conditions are not so great ether. Perhaps you could also rethink your datamodel. But what you are trying to get is a union, so do union.